# Trying to install Heroes of Might & Magic III Complete on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: wine, games, playonlinux

So I downloaded PlayOnLinux (along with wine) and purchased the game on gog.com.  Downloaded the setup file and tried to install with it via playonlinux.  Towards the end of the installation I get an error at a memory address which throws everything off.  Here is the log:

```
Unhandled exception: page fault on read access to 0x00001970 in 32-bit code (0x00001970).
Register dump:
 CS:0023 SS:002b DS:002b ES:002b FS:0063 GS:006b
 EIP:00001970 ESP:0033fb40 EBP:0033fcfc EFLAGS:00210202(  R- --  I   - - - )
 EAX:00000001 EBX:7c70ade0 ECX:f77c2000 EDX:00000000
 ESI:00000001 EDI:7d807eac
Stack dump:
0x0033fb40:  f77ad974 f77c2918 f77c2c08 7c6dd340
0x0033fb50:  7c6ddb68 7c6decb0 7c6df490 7c6def90
0x0033fb60:  7c6df768 7c6e0228 7c6e0668 7c6e0ac0
0x0033fb70:  7c6e0ec8 7c6e1330 7c6e17b8 7c6e1b58
0x0033fb80:  7c6e1f08 7c6e2298 7c6e2688 7c6e2a90
0x0033fb90:  7c6e2f20 7c6e32e0 7c6e37d8 7c6e4b50
Backtrace:
=>0 0x00001970 (0x0033fcfc)
  1 0xf7498973 in libc.so.6 (+0x2e972) (0xf761d1e0)
  2 0xf74989cf exit+0x1e() in libc.so.6 (0x0033fdfc)
  3 0x7bc5f496 NtTerminateProcess+0x65() in ntdll (0x0033fdfc)
  4 0x7b85f96f process_ExitProcess+0x2e() in kernel32 (0x0033fe1c)
  5 0x7b85d0d2 ExitProcess+0x11() in kernel32 (0x0033fe30)
  6 0x00405197 in setup_homm3_complete_2.0.0.16.tmC:\users\gyrfalcon\Temp\is-FROP6.tmp\setup_homm3_complete_2.0.0.16.tmp (+0x5196) (0x004fe7f0)
0x00001970: -- no code accessible --
Modules:
Module  Address         Debug info  Name (112 modules)
PE    400000-  537000   Export          setup_homm3_complete_2.0.0.16.tmC:\users\gyrfalcon\Temp\is-FROP6.tmp\setup_homm3_complete_2.0.0.16.tmp
ELF 78ca9000-7b800000   Deferred        libllvm-3.8.so.1
ELF 7b800000-7b8fe000   Dwarf           kernel32<elf>
  \-PE  7b810000-7b8fe000   \               kernel32
ELF 7bc00000-7bcc3000   Dwarf           ntdll<elf>
  \-PE  7bc10000-7bcc3000   \               ntdll
ELF 7bf00000-7bf03000   Deferred        <wine-loader>
ELF 7c0ea000-7c200000   Deferred        libasound.so.2
ELF 7c6b1000-7c6dd000   Deferred        winealsa<elf>
ELF 7c7ed000-7c80f000   Deferred        mmdevapi<elf>
  \-PE  7c7f0000-7c80f000   \               mmdevapi
ELF 7c80f000-7c846000   Deferred        libtxc_dxtn.so
ELF 7c846000-7c862000   Deferred        libbsd.so.0
ELF 7c862000-7c885000   Deferred        libtinfo.so.5
ELF 7c885000-7c8bc000   Deferred        libedit.so.2
ELF 7c8bc000-7c8c5000   Deferred        libffi.so.6
ELF 7c8c5000-7c8e2000   Deferred        libgcc_s.so.1
ELF 7ca59000-7ca75000   Deferred        libelf.so.1
ELF 7ca75000-7ca80000   Deferred        libdrm_amdgpu.so.1
ELF 7ca80000-7ca8e000   Deferred        libdrm_radeon.so.1
ELF 7ca8e000-7ca98000   Deferred        libdrm_nouveau.so.2
ELF 7ca98000-7d658000   Deferred        swrast_dri.so
ELF 7d658000-7d66a000   Deferred        libdrm.so.2
ELF 7d66a000-7d670000   Deferred        libxcb-dri2.so.0
ELF 7d670000-7d68b000   Deferred        libxcb-glx.so.0
ELF 7d68b000-7d68e000   Deferred        libx11-xcb.so.1
ELF 7d68e000-7d692000   Deferred        libxdamage.so.1
ELF 7d692000-7d6ae000   Deferred        libglapi.so.0
ELF 7d6ae000-7d6b1000   Deferred        libxshmfence.so.1
ELF 7d6b1000-7d6b9000   Deferred        libxcb-sync.so.1
ELF 7d6b9000-7d6bd000   Deferred        libxcb-present.so.0
ELF 7d6bd000-7d6c1000   Deferred        libxcb-dri3.so.0
ELF 7d6c1000-7d730000   Deferred        libgl.so.1
ELF 7d730000-7d800000   Deferred        opengl32<elf>
  \-PE  7d750000-7d800000   \               opengl32
ELF 7d800000-7d809000   Deferred        librt.so.1
ELF 7d826000-7d839000   Deferred        sfc_os<elf>
  \-PE  7d830000-7d839000   \               sfc_os
ELF 7d839000-7d84c000   Deferred        sfc<elf>
  \-PE  7d840000-7d84c000   \               sfc
ELF 7d99d000-7d9da000   Deferred        usp10<elf>
  \-PE  7d9a0000-7d9da000   \               usp10
ELF 7dbd7000-7dd03000   Deferred        wined3d<elf>
  \-PE  7dbe0000-7dd03000   \               wined3d
ELF 7dd03000-7dd67000   Deferred        ddraw<elf>
  \-PE  7dd10000-7dd67000   \               ddraw
ELF 7de4f000-7de70000   Deferred        imm32<elf>
  \-PE  7de60000-7de70000   \               imm32
ELF 7de87000-7deba000   Deferred        uxtheme<elf>
  \-PE  7de90000-7deba000   \               uxtheme
ELF 7deba000-7dec1000   Deferred        libxfixes.so.3
ELF 7dec1000-7decc000   Deferred        libxcursor.so.1
ELF 7df6e000-7df98000   Deferred        libexpat.so.1
ELF 7df98000-7dfe1000   Deferred        libfontconfig.so.1
ELF 7dfe1000-7dff4000   Deferred        libxi.so.6
ELF 7dff4000-7dff8000   Deferred        libxcomposite.so.1
ELF 7dff8000-7e005000   Deferred        libxrandr.so.2
ELF 7e005000-7e011000   Deferred        libxrender.so.1
ELF 7e011000-7e018000   Deferred        libxxf86vm.so.1
ELF 7e018000-7e01f000   Deferred        libxdmcp.so.6
ELF 7e01f000-7e045000   Deferred        libxcb.so.1
ELF 7e045000-7e04b000   Deferred        libuuid.so.1
ELF 7e04b000-7e196000   Deferred        libx11.so.6
ELF 7e196000-7e1ab000   Deferred        libxext.so.6
ELF 7e1ab000-7e1c5000   Deferred        libice.so.6
ELF 7e1c5000-7e1ce000   Deferred        libsm.so.6
ELF 7e1ce000-7e258000   Deferred        winex11<elf>
  \-PE  7e1e0000-7e258000   \               winex11
ELF 7e258000-7e283000   Deferred        libpng12.so.0
ELF 7e283000-7e297000   Deferred        libz.so.1
ELF 7e297000-7e347000   Deferred        libfreetype.so.6
ELF 7e364000-7e3a0000   Deferred        winspool<elf>
  \-PE  7e370000-7e3a0000   \               winspool
ELF 7e3a0000-7e47f000   Deferred        comdlg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e3b0000-7e47f000   \               comdlg32
ELF 7e47f000-7e4ea000   Deferred        shlwapi<elf>
  \-PE  7e490000-7e4ea000   \               shlwapi
ELF 7e4ea000-7e6fb000   Deferred        shell32<elf>
  \-PE  7e500000-7e6fb000   \               shell32
ELF 7e6fb000-7e7ee000   Deferred        comctl32<elf>
  \-PE  7e700000-7e7ee000   \               comctl32
ELF 7e7ee000-7e813000   Deferred        mpr<elf>
  \-PE  7e7f0000-7e813000   \               mpr
ELF 7e813000-7e826000   Deferred        msimg32<elf>
  \-PE  7e820000-7e826000   \               msimg32
ELF 7e826000-7e89c000   Deferred        rpcrt4<elf>
  \-PE  7e830000-7e89c000   \               rpcrt4
ELF 7e89c000-7e99d000   Deferred        gdi32<elf>
  \-PE  7e8b0000-7e99d000   \               gdi32
ELF 7e99d000-7eadd000   Deferred        user32<elf>
  \-PE  7e9b0000-7eadd000   \               user32
ELF 7eadd000-7eb3e000   Deferred        advapi32<elf>
  \-PE  7eaf0000-7eb3e000   \               advapi32
ELF 7eb3e000-7ec44000   Deferred        ole32<elf>
  \-PE  7eb60000-7ec44000   \               ole32
ELF 7ec44000-7ed53000   Deferred        oleaut32<elf>
  \-PE  7ec60000-7ed53000   \               oleaut32
ELF 7ed53000-7ed66000   Deferred        libnss_files.so.2
ELF 7ed66000-7ed73000   Deferred        libnss_nis.so.2
ELF 7ed73000-7ed8e000   Deferred        libnsl.so.1
ELF 7ef8e000-7efe3000   Deferred        libm.so.6
ELF 7efe4000-7efe8000   Deferred        libxinerama.so.1
ELF 7efe8000-7f000000   Deferred        version<elf>
  \-PE  7eff0000-7f000000   \               version
ELF f7460000-f7464000   Deferred        libxau.so.6
ELF f7465000-f746a000   Deferred        libdl.so.2
ELF f746a000-f7620000   Dwarf           libc.so.6
ELF f7620000-f763d000   Deferred        libpthread.so.0
ELF f7650000-f765a000   Deferred        libnss_compat.so.2
ELF f765b000-f779c000   Dwarf           libwine.so.1
ELF f779e000-f77c3000   Deferred        ld-linux.so.2
ELF f77c5000-f77c6000   Deferred        [vdso].so
Threads:
process  tid      prio (all id:s are in hex)
0000000e services.exe
    0000001f    0
    0000001e    0
    00000015    0
    00000010    0
    0000000f    0
00000012 winedevice.exe
    0000001a    0
    00000014    0
    00000013    0
0000001b plugplay.exe
    00000020    0
    0000001d    0
    0000001c    0
00000024 explorer.exe
    00000025    0
00000028 setup_homm3_complete_2.0.0.16.exe
    00000029    0
0000002a (D) C:\users\gyrfalcon\Temp\is-FROP6.tmp\setup_homm3_complete_2.0.0.16.tmp
    0000002b    0 <==
System information:
    Wine build: wine-1.5.16
    Platform: i386
    Host system: Linux
    Host version: 4.4.0-31-generic
```

I know that playonlinux works with gog because I did the same procedure with installing Alpha Centauri.  Nothing online seems to tell me how I can get HoMMIII onto Ubuntu 16.04.  LMK if I can provide any other details please.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: Sorry. I misinterpreted your comment saying there was no entry. I was also busy with tasks and didn't look it up myself. Sorry on my part. Also, I think the Wine AppDB isn't version or distro specific. It's Wine, so the instructions should be universal.

Comment: I also would like to welcome you to Ask Ubuntu, and hope you have better experiences than this one. :)

Comment: No problem. Also, to prevent this comments section from spiraling infinitely, can you delete your previous comments? It'll make room for future discussion.

Comment: "boss" hey i got promoted! :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of games from GOG give me the **memory address** error at the end of the install, but after pressing 3-4 times okay it just ends the install, and I am able to add the shortcut.

If the dialogue does not appear to add a shortcut, you can try adding it manually by going to **Configure => Create new shortcut for this virtual drive**

Comment: This was exactly what I needed to do.  Thank you.

Comment: UPDATE:  For anyone trying to download HoMM3 mod for it just go to playonlinux, search the game and install HD.  They will provide you a link to the latest HD version to download (https://sites.google.com/site/heroes3hd/) and continue installation.  You do not have to go into **configure** and create a new shortcut like the previous step.